# How do you quit a Forth environment?

Tags: forth

If I am in a Forth environment, how do I leave, and how do I program a word to leave?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to 'leave' Forth code, depending on what you need to do.

## `BYE`

The Forth standard defines the word `BYE` to leave the Forth environment itself.

> `BYE` ( -- )
> Return control to the host operating system, if any.

This word gets a lot of creative interpretations when your Forth is *not* running as a program in an operating system. For example, on some systems where Forth *is* the operating system, `BYE` causes the system to restart instead, letting you load another OS.

`BYE` is part of the Programming-Tools Extensions word set.

## `QUIT`

There is a word in the Core word set called `QUIT`, but it does not leave the environment. Instead, it leaves execution of a word and returns you back to the interpreter. This is why it is called 'QUIT', it is *quitting* in another sense.

> `QUIT` ( -- ) ( R: *i***x* -- )
> Empty the return stack, store zero in `SOURCE-ID` if it is present, make user input device the input source, and enter interpretation state. Do not display a message. Repeat the following:
>
> - Accept a line from the input source into the input buffer, set `>IN` to zero, and interpret.
> - Display the implementation-defined system prompt if in interpretation state, all processing has been completed, and no ambiguous condition exists.

Rather than defining `QUIT` as something like "this word returns you to the interpreter", instead `QUIT` is really defined as *the interpreter itself* in the Forth standard. In a factored Forth implementation, this makes sense: the word that puts you back in the interpreter and the interpreter itself can be the same word, they both can just clear the return stack and start interpreting.

And `QUIT` is the word you are more likely to see used in colon definitions, because it is a convenient way to break out of a stack of word executions, leaving the current contents of the data stack as-is, and returning to the interpreter. You can, of course, use `BYE` in a colon definition, for example in a custom interpreter or environment written in Forth to exit back to the operating system.